# How to automatically increase the mic volume in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, microphone

Is there a way to increase the mic volume of a flash application automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Gain](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Microphone.html#gain) function where ever you want to change it.

```
gain(50);
```

where 50 is normal "volume"

0 is none.

100 is maximum.

Comment: Can you change the volume of the sound received by the Microphone?

Comment: @Joy I am not entirely sure what you mean